# SQL Update based on parts of another field

Tags: sql

I need to update a field based on partial matches of another.  "Field2" is a constant 4 characters in length.  What I was trying to do was have it look at Field2 and if it started with an F then update Field1 to 340.  Then if it starts with an F and the 3rd character is a 3 then update field1 to 344 and so on.

Basically, 340 would be the rule when field2 starts with F and F*3* would be the exception and needs to be called 344.

The problem of course is that using 'like F*3*' is not actually looking for a 3 in the third position but rather anywhere after the F.

Is there a way to do this?  I appreciate any help.

Jim

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE [Table] SET [Table].[Field1] = ""340"" WHERE (([Table]![Field2] Like ""F*""));", -1
DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE [Table] SET [Table].[Field1] = ""344"" WHERE (([Table]![Field2] Like ""F*3*""));", -1
DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE [Table] SET [Table].[Field1] = ""343"" WHERE (([Table]![Field2] Like ""F*4*""));", -1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your conditions can be specific to what you want to match, so don't use the wildcard at all.

Consider that your first condition can be `LEFT([Field2],1) = 'F'`

Your second condition can use [SUBSTRING()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx)

```
LEFT([field2],1) = 'F' AND SUBSTRING([field2],3,1) = '3'
```

This way, you're matching where the first character is 'F' and the third character is '3'

Comment: Thanks for the lightning fast reply!  MS Access does not like substring() but I was able to use mid() in its place for the same result.  It is now doing what I want it to do.

Comment: @JR in the future, please tag your question with the specific database you're using... Then people can make sure their answers' syntax is applicable! Glad I could help.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind for next time, thanks again for the help.